# Screen brightness Samsung R519 with kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, brightness

Kubuntu recognizes the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd> but it only changes the brightness when it goes from 85% to 71% or viceversa. I want to know an easy way to change the screen brightness. I don't care if the method doesn't use the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. I don't have installed the Nvidia drivers because kubuntu doesn't worked when I installed it and I had to reinstall kubuntu. I found [this method](https://code.google.com/p/ubuntu-brightness-laptop-r519/) but I don't know if ubuntu solutions work in kubuntu (let me know that too).

Software:

```
 - Release: `cat /etc/lsb-release | grep DISTRIB_RELEASE=` Kubuntu 14.04
 - KDE version `kde4-config -v`: 4.13.3
 - GRUB version: `apt-cache show grub | grep ersion` 0.97-29ubuntu66
 - There's no other OS
```

Hardware:

- Samsung NP-R519 laptop
- CPU make: `lscpu`

  ```
  Architecture:          i686
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
  CPU(s):                2
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
  Thread(s) per core:    1
  Core(s) per socket:    2
  Socket(s):             1
  Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
  CPU family:            6
  Model:                 23
  Stepping:              10
  CPU MHz:               2100.000
  BogoMIPS:              4189.53
  L1d cache:             32K
  L1i cache:             32K
  L2 cache:              1024K
  ```
- GPU manufacturer and model: `lspci | grep aphic`

  ```
  Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Graphics Port (rev 07)
  ```

  `lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12`

  ```
  01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [GeForce G 105M] [10de:0a68] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
      Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c059]
      Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
      Memory at cc000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
      Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
      Memory at ce000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
      I/O ports at 2000 [size=128]
      [virtual] Expansion ROM at cd000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
      Capabilities: <access denied>
      Kernel driver in use: nouveau

  02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
  Subsystem: Askey Computer Corp. Device [144f:7167]
  ```
- RAM: `sudo dmidecode --type 17` 2 GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backlight control should work by default when using the open source nouveau driver.
Instead, if you use the closed source nvidia driver, follow these instructions:
Start "NVIDIA X Server Setting" from menu or type in a terminal:

```
sudo nvidia-settings
```

Select "X Server Display Configuration" from the left hand menu.
Push button "Save to X Configuration File".
Push button "Show preview...".
Add the line

```
Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```

to Device section. It should look similar like this:

```
Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device0"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName      "GeForce GT 330M"
Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

Uncheck "Merge with existing file".

Save the file to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.

Reboot and check if backlight control works.